# Error 401 when login twitter by twitter4j

Tags: android

I am doing an app android to login and upload photo to twitter.

I used twitter4j to login and reference some tutorial..I extract that consumer key and consumer secret key are filled correct.But I encountered an error"401: Authentication credential...".Have a solution to fix it is sync time my server with time twitter server..But I don't understand what sync time here and how to extractly..

Can you help me.

Comment: Personally I'd use OAuth instead of twitter4j

Comment: I thought this just meant make sure the time on your phone is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

You have not entered wrong Consumer Key or Secret Key from your Created Application in Twitter.

Ensure that you gave the two keys also ensure that it is correct.

[This](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application) Tutorial will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I was having that trouble, finally, the solution was to put a valid callback url in my twitter api (https://dev.twitter.com/‎) I used google+ url and that's it. The error dissapeared and now I can tweet with my app.